# I want to add surface selection feature via three.js library

Tags: object, three.js, highlight, surface

I want to add surface selection or highlighter to my webgl codes. I want to highlight when i click to the surface. Is there anyone can help me about this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please, read about [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score -2):

Read about raycasting here:
That gets you the object/triangle... then you can attach some indicator to the clicked surface.
https://threejs.org/examples/?q=raycast